# How to make a server call with out dispatch async instance in gwt

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt-platform

I am using using GWT2.3 with GWTP. Now in this application I need to make a server side call from a non presenter class (So there id no dispatch async instance).
Here is my class

```
public class NameTokenHandler implements ValueChangeHandler<String> {
    @Inject
    DispatchAsync dispatchAsync;
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
        if (event != null) {
            String nameToken = event.getValue();

            if(dispatchAsync!=null)
            {
                System.out.println("yes");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No");
            }

            History.newItem(nameToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Here dispatchAsync is always null. I am getting from where it should be initialized so that I can make a server side call. If there is any other way then please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you create the class `NameTokenHandler`?

Comment: @sydney just by immplementing ValueChangeHandler....as above

Comment: Do you call a `new NameTokenHandler()` to create the object?

Comment: yes I have added this to history.

Answer (score 2):

You need to inject the `NameTokenHandler`, so your dispatcher will be injected too.

```
public class C {

  private NameTokenHandler handler;

  @Inject
  public C(NameTokenHandler handler) {
    this.handler = handler;
  }

}
```

This way the handler will be injected to the `C` class, and your dispatcher will also be injected in the `NameTokenHandler`. BTW you might need to have a constructor in `NameTokenHandler` that follows the same pattern (`DispatchAsync` as a parameter).